# Installing Error of Shapely and GDAL on pydroid

Tags: python-3.x, pip, libraries, c-libraries, pydroid

Pydroid is a good app for beginners and others for running python on android. I could install many useful libraries without any problems, but I don't understand why some libraries such as [GDAL](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/), [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/), [Pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) could not be installed.

Installation Error:

```sh
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-1glqlnnp/shapely/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-1glqlnnp/shapely/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-1glqlnnp/shapely/pip-egg-info
             cwd: /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-1glqlnnp/shapely/
        Complete output (11 lines):
        Failed `CDLL(libgeos_c.so.1)`
        Failed `CDLL(libgeos_c.so)`
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-1glqlnnp/shapely/setup.py", line 80, in <module>
            from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
          File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-1glqlnnp/shapely/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 167, in <module>
            fallbacks=['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'])
          File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-1glqlnnp/shapely/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 161, in load_dll
            libname, fallbacks or []))
        OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    /storage/emulated/0 $
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am running Android Nougat Version 7.0 and Pydroid 3 (python3).

Answer (score 1):

The three python module you mention all depend on C libraries, i.e. they are not pure python but provide an interface to lower level functions. Specifically, the three mentioned python modules need these libraries:

1. [GDAL](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) is toolset for the [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) library
2. [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/), as your error message suggests depends on [Geos](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/)
3. [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) is an interface for [proj](http://proj.org/)

As such, you would need to download and compile these libraries yourself for your system (or find pre-compiled binaries, but that sounds unlikely for your setup). Only then would you be able to install and use the corresponding python modules.

Comment: Would you let me know how to compile such libraries for my android, for example tutorial or sthg. in English or in German. I tried to search and search to install such libraries on pydroid but I didnt find it :( , and thank you for your informations that you gave me