# How do I put a .tar.gz typed file in path for python on my pydroid

Tags: python, path, tar, webp, pydroid

**Step - 1**
I've downloaded a webp support of linux for my Android, it is currently in the path :-
*/storage/emulated/0/Download/libwebp-1.2.0-linux-x86-64.tar.gz*

**Step - 2**
I've tried :-
*python -m pip install /storage/emulated/0/Download/libwebp-1.2.0-linux-x86-64.tar.gz*

**Step - 3**
It threw me this error :-

````
Processing ./Download/libwebp-1.2.0-linux-x86-64.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-req-build-dlhd5s9x/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-req-build-dlhd5s9x/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-pip-egg-info-pg74pb7t
         cwd: /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-req-build-dlhd5s9x/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 392, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-req-build-dlhd5s9x/setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/libwebp-1.2.0-linux-x86-64.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
/storage/emulated/0 $```
````

Comment: I assume it is necessary to extract its content first.

Comment: could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944393/installing-error-of-shapely-and-gdal-on-pydroid